# what is the difference between tangent and slope of tangent?

Tags: circles, curves

I need your help, my question is what is the difference between tangent and slope of tangent ?

A clear example would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tangent to a curve at a point is a straight line just touching the curve at that point; the slope of the tangent is the **gradient** of that straight line.

Here's a picture to help.

[image]

The green line is the tangent line to the point $(1,1)$. It is a geometric object.

The slope at $(1,1)=2$ (if you want to know why, it's to do with differentiating, or finding the gradient of the tangent at a point). This is a number.

So, to conclude: the tangent's a line; the slope is a number.

Qualitatively, your question is equivalent to the following:

"What's the difference between a hill and the steepness of a hill?".

To answer your second question (in the comments):
$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{\textrm{change in y}}{\textrm{change in x}}=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\rm{gradient}$$ (we can see this from the right-angled triangle, if we use some basic trigonometry).

Comment: does that mean that  when we compute the tan(theta) we get the slop    of the tangent.

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: theta is the angle

Comment: If $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent and the horizontal, then, yes: $\tan(\theta)=\rm{slope}$.

Comment: yes , thank you so much, that was very useful.

Comment: Picture made with $\LaTeX$ of 1950.

Answer (score 2):

The English word 'Tangent' also means the tangent line (at a point of a circle, say), and its slope is the numeric value $\tan(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the angle of the tangent line and the right wing and (any parallel to) the $x$-axis.